# Prove that real line and parabola are topologically same but different geometrically?

Tags: general-topology

As far I know I need to find a homeomorphism. 
So if I consider a real line then $f: \Bbb R \to P$ defined by $f(x)=(x,x²)$ where $P=$ parabola.
I have problem with continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $f: X \to Y$ is a continuous function, and $\mathrm{gr}(f)$ is the graph of $f$, then $\mathrm{gr}(f)$ is homeomorphic to $X$. We want to find an homeomorphism between $\{(x,f(x)) ~:~x \in X\}$ and $X$. The map: $$X \ni x \mapsto (x, f(x)) \in \mathrm{gr}(f)$$
does the job, since it is bijective, continuous (both components are continuous), and the inverse is simply the projection $$\mathrm{gr}(f) \ni (x, f(x)) \mapsto x \in X$$ which is obviously continuous. Your exercise is a particular case of this, with $X = Y = \Bbb R$ and $\mathrm{gr}(f) = P$.

Comment: and what about graphically difference ?

Comment: I would argue by differential geometry. Curvature is not a topological invariant. $\alpha_1(t) = (t,0)$ has zero curvature, and $\alpha_2(t) = (t, t^2)$ has non-zero curvature.

Comment: IS IT ENOUGH TO SAY LINE HAS CONSTANT SLOPE BUT PARABOLA DOSE'NT HAS ?